# Creating dataframes for each iterations through a file directory using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to create a script which parses through a directory of .xlsx files where it will create one large dataframe for further filtering and analysis.

I have checked through lots of posts on this but haven't found one that matches what I am trying to attempt.

I do not have a lot of experience with coding, mostly adapting other people's old VBA code to fit my purposes. I am learning Python to write code from scratch and hopefully it'll be more efficient than what I am currently using. See my script below, it currently returns the final file's dataframe; I tried an appended formula but it appended the first row instead of the whole dataframe for each iteration.

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    #Pulls all the files names in a given directory
    data = []
    model_path = 'C:\\working\path\for\files\' #hard coded for each directory for now
    with os.scandir(model_path) as batch:
        for model in batch:
            if not model.name.startswith("~"): #excludes temporary/recovery excel files
                #print(model.name)
                model_name = os.path.join(model_path, model.name)
                #print(model_name) #confirms the correct directory is being opened and models parsed
                df_model_DCF = pd.read_excel(model_name)
         print(df_model_DCF)
```

I guess I need to create an empty dataframe for each iterations to write the results to on each run through hence the data variable at the top but I cannot see how to append this to the bottom of the previous dataframe's data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So before your `for` loop, initialize an empty dataframe, say, ```total_df = pd.DataFrame()``` Inside the for loop, you could do, ```total_df  = pd.concat([total_df, df_model_DCF], ignore_index=True)```

Comment: That seems to do what I wanted! Thanks alot!